# I cant get to set desire time of AlarmCLock in Android

Tags: android

Hi guys this is what i have so far:

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mainactivity, 0, intent, 0);
             Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
             calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
             calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
             AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
             alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
             showmsg();
```

the alarm comes after 10 seconds How can I make it in desire time i want, I have set a timepicker so how can i do it depending on the timepickers time to ring the alarm?

Thanx.

Comment: How did my answer work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

With your `TimePicker`, call `picker.getCurrentHour()` and `picker.getCurrentMinute()`. Use these values to calculate the total milliseconds of the given time of day (12:00 pm would equal 43200000 ms, for example) by multiplying by the milliseconds in an hour (3600000) or minute (60000). Then get the milliseconds of today's date when it started at 0:00. That would all look like this:

```
//time of day in ms
long totalTimePickerMs = (picker.getCurrentHour() * 3600000) + (picker.getCurrentMinute() * 60000); 

//today's date in ms
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Date d = c.getTime();
long today = d.getDay() + d.getMonth() + d.getYear();
long total = today + totalTimePickerMs;
```

Essentially you are getting today at midnight (0:00) in milliseconds and adding to it the milliseconds of the specific time of day.

Then like you did before, except set the alarm with `total` as the second parameter.